# Changing values in a numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

#df_len : length of a column in pandas dataframe

temp = np.zeros(df_len)
for i in range(df_len):
    temp[i] = (i+1)*0.25
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I recommend that you learn about broadcasting with numpy. This is a technique that makes it so you almost never use explicit loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `arange` function to create an array of integers from 0 to `df_len - 1`, and then multiply each integer by 0.25:

```
import numpy as np

df_len = 10 # example length

temp = np.arange(df_len) * 0.25

print(temp)
```